# Взболтнуть — лишнего или лишнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, управление, разговорная-речь

> Осознав, что **взболтнул лишнего**, Буаробер, придвинув стул, уселся рядом с Тео, положив ладони на колени, разглаживая ветхий бархат своих потертых кюлотов.
> [С. Арденн. Черный граф](https://books.google.ee/books?id=0CvKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&lpg=PT72&dq=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=JruTFZX69D&sig=ACfU3U10ZNcwqU8K4uILxNXBZA0Pawl5wg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFlY7TwrztAhXNHXcKHfqvD8QQ6AEwC3oECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&f=false)

> — Разве я **взболтнул лишнее**? — жмурится Ваня. Веселый парень...
> [Е. Лехт. Израиль в Москве](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=67589&p=22)

Была в гостях — обсуждали это слово в прошедшие выходные (в словаре управления глагол не нашли).
*Взболтнуть **лишнего*** или *взболтнуть **лишнее*** — как же правильно говорить?

P. S. [Кюлоты](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc3p/173446/%D0%9A%D0%AE%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%AB)

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю, что тут дело не в глаголе. Само по себе использование глагола взболтать (взболтнуть) в таком значении вызывает вопросы, новояз какой-то, но в принципе ничего принципиально отличного от общей схемы тут быть не должно. Общий же подход допускает двоякое управление.
Сказать, выпить, съесть лишнее - сказать, выпить, съесть лишнего.
При этом второй вариант выглядит гораздо более естественным в разговорной речи.

> Он лишнего поел,
> И тут как раз ему живот схватило!

Михалков, Без вины пострадавшие.

(+) ===
Мне странно, что в конструкции "взболтнуть лишнего/лишнее" обсуждается именно второе слово. По мне так очевидная нелепица - именно глагол. "Сболтнул лишнего" - вот я бы понял. В подтверждение - цитата из конкурсной работы учителя русского, победителя областного Вологодского конкурса 2015 г. "За образцовое владение русским языком в профессиональной деятельности" Ксении Елистратовой:

> <...> Не поленитесь, зайдите на любой форум. Люди пишут (и пишут они
> это не в порядке «стеба»): «канать в лету», «кануть в лето», «многое
> лето», «рыдать на взрыв», «обвенчаться успехом», ***«взболтнуть лишнее»***,
> «зомбировать почву», «плот воображения», «дать обед молчания», «бойня
> титанов», «ни в суп ногой», «навоз и ныне там», «носиться со списанной
> торбой», «у горбатого могила справа», «воздастся с торицей», «до
> белого колена», «в ежовых рукавах», «встать на дубы», «во тьме
> таракани», «наладом дышит», «как Христос за пазухой», «притча
> воязыцы», «те пуньте вам на язык», «из-за кромов», «агниевы конюшни»,
> «пожимать плоды», «через трение к звездам»...

Источник: https://35media.ru/articles/2015/10/23/pedagogi-shkol-i-detskih-sadov-vladeyut-russkim-yazykom
(курсив мой - b-s)

Показательный ряд, не правда ли?

(++) ======

> Но всё-таки я присоединяюсь к Римминому вопросу: лишнего или лишнее?

Если закрыть глаза на неправильное употребление глагола, то тут "лишнего" выглядит предпочтительнее, значение тут - немного, чуть больше возможного или необходимого, поэтому партитив (второй родительный). Об этом же и у Михалкова, да и в других примерах.

Но я уже несколько раз говорил, что не считаю возможным всерьез обсуждать стилистическую правильность отдельных слов в изначально неверных (грамматически и семантически) оборотах. Не могу сейчас сослаться на конкретного *авторитета*, но у меня это, что называется, с младых ногтей впитано.

Comment: Уже поставил плюс, но понял, что не совсем удовлетворён ответом. Насчёт глагола, считаю, вы верно подметили. Но всё-таки я присоединяюсь к Римминому вопросу: *лишнего* или *лишнее?*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ну я же ответил... В правильной конструкции "лишнего" - предпочтительнее. Ладно, напишу русским по белому.

Comment: А поделитесь идеей, почему у вас в слове "римминому" буква М удвоена?  Я, правда, встал в тупик, не знаю, как оно правильно, но мне режет глаз, как, впрочем, и заглавная Р. А заодно все это дает мне лишнее основание относиться к с большой опаской ко всякого рода "преобразованиям" ников... (ПС) У меня это пунктик такой, но он берет начало в древние времена Интернета, когда сетевой этикет вообще резко негативно относился к коверканью ников. Но сейчас я исключительно про конкретный случай.

Comment: *Но я уже несколько раз говорил, что не считаю возможным всерьез обсуждать стилистическую правильность отдельных слов в изначально неверных (грамматически и семантически) оборотах.* Полностью согласен, но я мысленно предлагал обсудить оборот ***с**болтнуть лишнего,* который вы признали нормальным.

Comment: ОК. Извините. Впрочем, я по сути-то ответил.

Comment: Хм... "Римма" же с двумя пишется. И разве *Машин, Петин* и т. д. не с большой пишутся? И почему ник?

Comment: Про заглавную - это да, я неудачно выразился. Мне режет имеено в слове Риммин - именно тогда когда оно с двумя М. А Мишин и Петин - нет. А вот со всем остальным, ником и удвоенной буквой, видимо надо разбираться отдельно. Я не в коей мере не говорю, что у вас ошибка орфографическая, я действительно недопонимаю этого принципа, почему удвоенная согласная тут сохраняется... А про ник - это у меня вообще челесть выпала. То есть вы реальное имя (предположим, что оно реальное) не воспринимаете как ник, если оно используется как ник? н-да... Отстал я от жизни. Навсегда.

Comment: Ладно, до лучших времен... Не в форме я сейчас, похоже.

Comment: Да нет, не воспринимаю как ник, верю, что оно реальное. :) Даже если псевдоним, человек к нему привыкает и отзывается как на имя. А что касается удвоения, я бы легко мог писать и с одной, но не знаю, как к этому отнесётся сама Римма. ;)

Comment: Артём, не хочу сейчас углублять, но с ником вы что-то перемудрили. Я не об этом спрашивал. Ник - это имя под которым один участник представляется системе (в этом случае - он же "логин") и другим соучастникам. То есть для меня нет разницы, насколько имя реальное. Вот например пару дней назад регистрировался по личной надобности в одной социальной сети. Так она мне без дураков предложила взять мое реальное имя ***в качестве ника***. И это постоянная ситуация, общепринятая. Мне казалось, что тут недопонимания быть просто не может. Видимо, я ошибался...

Comment: Думаю, Артём написал верно: Алла — Аллин (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD); Инна — Иннин; Римма — Риммин, Риммино (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD). Я не против.

Comment: Согласитесь, "съесть лишнего" - можно воспринять и подругому, где "лишний" одушевляется.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова да у меня м в мыслях не было утверждать, что написано неправильно. Что же до того, можно ли вообще использовать на форумах измененные формы ников (путь даже и с согласия носителя) - это вообще отдельный разговор, У меня есть возражения общего плана, ибо это сильно путает третьих участников, а движок и вовсе может поставить в тупик, но в конце концов все определяется сложившейся на конкретном ресурсе практикой. Обсуждать здесь и сейчас не буду еще и потому, что, как оказалось, с самим понятием "ник" надо разбираться, ибо нет единого  понимания.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я до сих пор не могу сформулировать, что и почему мне не понравилось в безусловно правильном, в чем уже ни секунды не сомневаюсь, написании Риммин. чтобы не бросать на полуслове мной же затеянный разговор, просто сформулирую, что в число таких режущих мне глаз написаний входят притяжательные , образованные от имен, не имеющих обычных безсуффиксальных усеченных форм (Римма, Алла, Жанна и проч.) А Аннин вызывает вопросы, поскольку есть Анин - от Аня. .

Comment: Это, понятно, чисто личные тараканы, возможно связаны с привычным мне с юных лет написанеием "Ганин" - была у меня (вернее сказать - у отца) хорошая знакомая Ганна Батьковна, которую все время норовили с одной Н написать, якобы на украинский манер, хотя там и по-украински Н удвоенная. ))) Но это вряд ли интересно кому-то, пишу, как сказал, просто чтобы какую-то точку поставить.

Comment: Аннин меня тоже напрягает. Нет, я с удовольствием буду писать с одной, если буду знать, что этим людям это приятно самим.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, есть примеры использования обоих вариантов, но на мой взгляд тут имеет место редкий лишительный падеж, возникающий у существительных при отрицающих глаголах:

"сказать лишн**ее**" (винительный: кого? что?),

но

"не сказать лишн**его**" (лишительный: без кого? без чего?).

То есть в современном русском это весьма мутная зона и приемлемы, скорее всего, оба варианта, но ноги растут, думаю, именно отсюда.

Comment: Не понял. Т. н. "лишительный падеж" - вещь действительно спорная - в том смысле, что можно ли его трактовать как нечто обособленное от родительного. Но не более, ничего сложного и мутного в нем нет. Да и вопрос-то не в этом. Лишительный - он строго при отрицании, а тут предлагается сделать выбор между вторым родительным (партитивом) и обычным винительным.

Answer (score 0):

Текст данного ответа удален автором.

Comment: Sharon, вы серьезно воспринимаете использование "взболтнуть" в этом значении как нечто нормативное, что вообще можно обсуждать на предмет употребительности и разницы в значениях?

Comment: Вопрос был о том, какой вариант  правильный. Я ответила, что возможны оба варианта. Но я  всегда стараюсь различить любые речевые варианты по смыслу,  даже если они разговорного характера. В данном случае это просто мое мнение, мне кажется, что разница есть. Примерно такая же, как для "выпить воды" и "выпить воду".

Comment: Простите, что поинтересовался вашим мнением. Хотелось бы еще услышать, о чем был мой вопрос. *Вопрос был о том, какой вариант правильный* - никакой. Вы с этим согласны или нет?

Comment: Взболтнуть?  А разве есть такое слово? Я думала - сболтнуть, про него и рассказываю. Нет, взболтнуть - так говорить нельзя.

Comment: По поводу ваших примеров. С Гоголем все понятно. Язык взболтнул - это нормально. Язык может не только болтать но и болтаться. Отсюда и этот оборот, ирония, едва ли не каламбур. А вот Омулевский (который мне как автор до сего дня был незнаком) заставил задуматься. Не знаю... Контекст нужен...

Comment: @Sharon Вот что нашлось в словаре Ефремовой: взболтну́ть — II _сов. перех._ и _неперех. разг._ Сказать что-либо необдуманно, ненамеренно; **сболтнуть.** (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/146206/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)